# Specflow with NUnit don't respect TestFixtureSetUpAttribute

Tags: nunit, structuremap, specflow

I'm using SpecFlow with Nunit and I'm trying to setup my enviroment tests using TestFixtureSetUpAttribute, but it's never called.

I already tried to use MSTests and ClassInitialize attribute, but the same happen. The function isn't called.

Any ideas Why?

```
[Binding]
public class UsersCRUDSteps
{
    [NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureSetUpAttribute()]
    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
        // THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER CALLER

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IDateTimeService>().Use<DateTimeService>();
        });

        throw new Exception("BBB");
    }

    private string username, password;

    [Given(@"I have entered username ""(.*)"" and password ""(.*)""")]
    public void GivenIHaveEnteredUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    [When(@"I press register")]
    public void WhenIPressRegister()
    {
    }

    [Then(@"the result should be default account created")]
    public void ThenTheResultShouldBeDefaultAccountCreated()
    {
    }
```

Solution:

```
[Binding]
public class UsersCRUDSteps
{
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void TestInitialize()
    {
        // THIS FUNCTION IS NEVER CALLER

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IDateTimeService>().Use<DateTimeService>();
        });

        throw new Exception("BBB");
    }

    private string username, password;

    [Given(@"I have entered username ""(.*)"" and password ""(.*)""")]
    public void GivenIHaveEnteredUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    [When(@"I press register")]
    public void WhenIPressRegister()
    {
    }

    [Then(@"the result should be default account created")]
    public void ThenTheResultShouldBeDefaultAccountCreated()
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `TestInitialize` is not called because it is inside your Steps class and not inside in an Unit Tests (because the actual unit test is inside the `.cs` which is generated from your `.feature` file).

SpecFlow has it's own test-lifetime events which are called hooks, these are all the predefined hooks:

- `[BeforeTestRun]` / `[AfterTestRun]`
- `[BeforeFeature]` / `[AfterFeature]`
- `[BeforeScenario]` / `[AfterScenario]`
- `[BeforeScenarioBlock]` / `[AfterScenarioBlock]`
- `[BeforeStep]` / `[AfterStep]`

Note that this allows for greater flexibility in setup. For additional information [see the documentation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks).

Based on the fact that you want to use the `TestFixtureSetUp` attribute you will probably need the `BeforeFeature` hook which will be called once before each feature, so you need to write:

```
[Binding]
public class UsersCRUDSteps
{
    [BeforeFeature]
    public static void TestInitialize()
    {               
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IDateTimeService>().Use<DateTimeService>();
        });

        throw new Exception("BBB");
    }

    //...
}
```

Note that the `[BeforeFeature]` attribute needs a `static` method.

You should also note that if you are using the VS integration there is an project item type called `SpecFlow Hooks (event bindings)` which creates a binding class with some predefined hooks to help you get started.

Comment: Thank you, it work. I only need to change my function to static